# Matching certain line of words between hashes

Tags: perl

i am trying to match this phone number between two files, and I found this code in the stackflow; [Compare file lines for match anywhere in second file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742013/compare-file-lines-for-match-anywhere-in-second-file)

```
    use strict;   #ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS
    use warnings; #ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS

    use autodie;  #Will end the program if files you try to open don't exist

    # Constants are a great way of storing data that is ...uh... constant
    use constant {
        FILE_1    =>  "a1.txt",
        FILE_2    =>  "a2.txt",
    };

my %phone_hash1;
my %phone_hash2;

open my $phone_num1_fh, "<", FILE_1;

while ( my $phone_num = <$phone_num1_fh> ) {
    chomp $phone_num;
    $phone_hash1{ $phone_num } = 1;
}
close $phone_num1_fh;

open my $phone_num2_fh, "<", FILE_2;

while ( my $phone_num = <$phone_num2_fh> ) {
    chomp $phone_num;
    $phone_hash2{ $phone_num } = 1;
}
close $phone_num2_fh;

my %in_common;

for my $phone ( keys %phone_hash1 ) {
    if ( $phone_hash2{$phone} ) { 
       $in_common{$phone} = 1;    #Phone numbers in common between the two lists
    }
}
for my $phone ( sort keys %phone_hash1 ) {
    if ( not $in_common{$phone} ) {
         print "Phone number $phone is only in the first file\n";
    }
}

for my $phone ( sort keys %phone_hash2 ) {
    if ( not $in_common{$phone} ) {
        print "Phone number $phone is only in " . FILE_2 . "\n";
    }
}

for my $phone ( sort keys %in_common ) {
    print "Phone number $phone is in both files\n";
}
```

The problem is; 
in my first file i need to filter out the phone number,
so, i try to make this;

```
 if ($s1 =~ m/(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+/) 
        {
        my $phone_num=($1."/".$2);
        chomp $phone_num;
        $phone_hash1{ $phone_num } = 1;
        }
```

my second file there is a path in front of the phone number
like alias/a/b/c/**0123456789**

and i don't know how to filter this one out into the hash, or filter out the things i dont want in the hash, so that i can compare this two numbers between two files.

```
($phone_hash2{ $phone_num }  =~ /.*$str/)
```

Comment: We could use some sample data here, and an example of what you're exactly trying to filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the prefix it is always the same in the content of the "second file"

```
alias/a/b/c/${phone_number_1}
alias/a/b/c/${phone_number_2}
alias/a/b/c/${phone_number_3}
```

Then the prefix can be removed by doing `substr`:

```
my $offset = length("alias/a/b/c/");
while(my $line = <$fh_file>) { 
    chomp($line);
    $line = substr($line, $offset);
}
```

If it is not the same prefix, since you mention that they looks like "path", I'm going to assume the last part of that path is the actual phone number. So the solution is simply: take the last part of the path. Which is also "the longest substring without any `/` in it anchored at the end of $line" (assuming the same while loop structure as above):

```
my ($phone) = $line =~ m{([^/]+)\z};
```

Or, from a different perspective: "Remove the longest prefix with a `/` at the end of it from $line, than take the rest of $line":

```
my $phone = $line =~ s{\A.+/}{}r;
```

And of course, if the phone number themselves can be enumerated with a easy pattern, e.g., `[0-9]{8}` (8 characters from the set of `[0123456789]`), perhaps it is more straightforward to just "take the part anchored at the end of $line matching the phone number pattern":

```
my ($phone) = $line =~ m{([0-9]{8})\z};
```

If none of the above covers your scenario, well... I'm just bad at guessing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the number out of a string like alias/a/b/c/0123456789 you could just use a pattern like /(\d+)/ if you are sure where are no numbers in the "path".

If you know the number is at the end of the path you can use /(\d+)$/

Comment: Thank you! using perl is easier than C programming.